# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware debug_toolbar.middleware: "No module named 'thread'"

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-debug-toolbar

I get "500 Internal Server Error" when I'm trying to enable django-debug-tool-bar. 
It's already installed and I have pasted this in settings.py :

```
if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.version.VersionDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings_vars.SettingsVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeaderDebugPanel',
    #'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request_vars.RequestVarsDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.template.TemplateDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CacheDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalDebugPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logger.LoggingPanel',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

My apache doesn't want to load properly the middleware :
apache error log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
     self.load_middleware()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware debug_toolbar.middleware: "No module named 'thread'"
```

I have tried to add the debug-toolbar-middleware at the top of the list but nothing change.
I'am using django 1.5 and python 3.3 and I have installed debug-toolbar with `python3.3 setup.py install`
What am I not seeing ?

Comment: it the path to get access to the file missing for apache.

Comment: Hum, maybe ! Where can I add this ?

Comment: Does debug-toolbar support Python 3.3?

Comment: You're right... It is not. I don't know if it's small change or big ones... Sometimes, you just need to fix the print function or replace a coma with "as" and it's work...